# Define the supports and resistances

Tags: programming, trading

When I day trade, I easily notice support and resistance areas. Visually it seems very intuitive to spot them, but I can't define them so that I can spot them using python. Can you give me a clear definition of these support and resistance zones? How can I code them in python?

Comment: Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/636

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate but this question is too broad and opinion based in any case.